# How to see how many unique strings Faker::Category_Here.whatever will provide?

Tags: ruby, faker

Having trouble figuring out how to take all examples of a string from a specific Faker class. For instance, in Ruby I can use, Faker::Compass.direction, and it will give a random direction. I can't do Faker::Compass.direction.all or .count to show me what's present within this class. Is there any way for me to access all the examples at once as an array?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [faker's I18n files](https://github.com/stympy/faker/tree/master/lib/locales) might be a good start.

For example, in the English I18n file for the compass namespace there are [32 different directions](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/locales/en/compass.yml) listed.